# Override a Joomla module. Return/render/echo Joomla full article without iframe

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

```
    public static function getArticle($id) {
    $db        = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query     = $db->getQuery(true);
    $db->setQuery(
      'SELECT `id`, `catid`, `title`, `alias` FROM #__content WHERE `id` = '.(int)$id.';'
    );

    try
    {
      $article = $db->loadObject();
    }

    catch (RuntimeException $e)
    {
      JError::raiseWarning(500, $e->getMessage());
    }
    if (!$article->id) return '';

    return '<iframe 
              src="'.JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->id.':'.$article->alias, $article->catid) . '&tmpl=component').'"
              frameborder="0" 
              width="100%" 
              height="100%" 
              >'.JText::_('COM_WRAPPER_NO_IFRAMES').'</iframe>';
    }
```

and this is the part of the code that renders the single article content:

```
              else if ($list_of_tabs['use'][$i][0] == 'article'){

        echo '<div class="tab-pane '.$active.'" id="'.$i.$rid.'">'.
                modJpTabsHelper::getArticle($list_of_tabs['article'][$i]).
             '</div>';
      }
```

The code above is a working function that displays a joomla article inside an iframe.

How can I get the same result without the iframe? I can´t find any solution on the internet that I can apply directly on this.

Thanks in advance

/Magnus

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Comment: After reading more about it on the internet it seems as this iframe approach is an easy way of rendering an article without any additional information. By using iframe source and passing tmpl=component in JRoute. Am I right? But I can´t find another solution that fits. Anyone who knows where to find it?